# Can I either download a sheet to a specific computer hard drive, or move a sheet in Backup and Sync to the hard drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Experts, thank you for spending your time on this!

I need to automatically download a Sheets file to a specific folder on a specific computer when a google script is triggered. I can think of two possible methods:

1. Download the file directly from Sheets/Drive (simulates the "Download As..." menu item).
2. Copy the file needed (already in the Google Drive folder of the local computer in question courtesy of Google Backup and Sync), then delete the source file from the Google Drive folder.

Is either method possible?

Currently, I am sending a pdf file to my Gmail, but I'd like to get the pdf file on my computer and bypass Gmail entirely.

I found a script (thank you Tanaike) but could not get it working. Here's a copy:

```
function downloadSheetAsPDF2() {
  var filename = "sampleFile.pdf"; // Please set the filename here.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();

  // Creat PDF file as a temporary file and create URL for downloading.
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.org/spreadsheets/d/" + ss.getId() + "/export?exportFormat=pdf&gid=" + sheetId + "&access_token=" + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName(filename);
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  var dlUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId();

  // Open a dialog and run Javascript for downloading the file.
  var str = '<script>window.location.href="' + dlUrl + '"</script>';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(str);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
  file.setTrashed(true);

  // This is used for closing the dialog.
  Utilities.sleep(3000);
  var closeHtml = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>google.script.host.close()</script>");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(closeHtml, "sample");
}
```

If there's anything that needs to be done to make this script operational, I'm all ears - and will be eternally grateful!

Comment: *but could not get it working.* Not descriptive enough. See [mcve]

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you in incognito?

Comment: I solved my issue - I realized that I already had the sheet I want to coming out as a PDF as an attachment to an email. I simply created another email account, and used Thunderbird as my email client. I can strip email attachments out using a Thunderbird add-in, and put the attachment files in a local folder.

Comment: Would you consider posting an answer explaining how you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would be happy to do so.

In the spirit of honesty, I need to say that this workflow is currently similar to "in beta testing". Right now, the workflow "works", but I don't have "reliable confidence" that it will always do what I want it to do in all conditions and circumstances. Time will tell. That said, I hope that someone will find what I have to say useful in some small way.

By way of background, let me explain why I had to develop this "workflow". I need to email my boss reports on a weekly basis. I expect that the "reports", now weekly, will soon become a daily chore, and be expanded company wide to hundreds of people. I wanted a solution that:

1. Was scalable,and could be expanded to multiple users.
2. Did NOT use any paid software - everything had to be open source.
3. Provided a "trackable" solution - if, at any time, something didn't work as planned, it was easy to debug and fix.
4. Was entirely "in-house". Sometimes, my reports contain sensitive data, so I didn't want to send any data to a third party firm.

To make this work, I used several apps:

1. Google Script
2. Two Gmail accounts (GM1 & GM2)
3. Thunderbird email client (installed on GM2)
4. Thunderbird add-in ("Filtaquilla")

I am required to use a company supplied template (in Google Sheets) to write my report. The report itself is a compilation of critical information (production output, machine health, preventive maintenance, etc...) gathered during the week. Every Monday morning, I start with an empty report template. By Friday afternoon, the report template is full, and is ready to be emailed to my boss.

Here is my workflow:

STEP 1

Late Friday afternoon, a Google Script trigger fires, causing a script to convert my report template from a Google Sheet to a pdf file. The pdf file is attached to a prewritten email and is emailed to the GM1 email account.

STEP 2

When the report email is received in the GM1 account, a filter in Gmail forwards the email (and report) to GM2.

STEP 3

When the report email is received in the GM2 account (where Thunderbird is installed), a filter in Thunderbird marks the email as read, and moves the email into "local folders". Additionally, the "Filtaquilla" add-in copies the attached report and saves it to a folder in the host computer's file structure.